# Show that $0$ is a limit point of $\{1/n\mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

Tags: metric-spaces

Given a subset $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ defined as $E:= \{1/n\mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ with usual metric, show that $0$ is a limit point of the set.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

you need to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ always is possible to find an element of the form $\frac{1}{n}$, such that $|0-\frac{1}{n}|<\epsilon$, or in an equivalent way, you need to find $n$ such that $\frac{1}{\epsilon}<n$. But remember that Archimedean property says that for any $r\in \mathbb{R}^+$ always exists a natural number $n$ such that $r<n$, now taking $\frac{1}{\epsilon}=r$ you are done.

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.